# C++ Optimization Involving Bool Settings

Tags: c++, optimization

Ok, so I'm looking for "the best way" to figure out how to deal with this.

I have booleans for a bunch of settings and want to store and access them a bit cleaner.

```
 -- Current
 bool MySetting1;
 bool MySetting2;
 bool MySetting3;
 bool MySetting4;
 .....
 Accessed with
 .....
 if (MySetting1)
```

In this example, I know what my settings are called and all that fun jazz.
I've thought over the options and looked around at maps and unordered maps and boolean vectors... I'm just looking for the most optimized way of doing things. Because the current way...is fine...it's just not very clean in my opinion.

```
enum myEnum
{
 SETTING_NAME1 = 0,
 SETTING_NAME2 = 0,
...
}
map<int,bool> myMap;
```

Is the access time doing myMap[SETTING_NAME1] the same as the current method? Is it a direct access or does it have to do a lookup?

**I just wanted to update and let everyone know the strategy I took.**

I used enum for identification

```
enum myEnum
{
 SETTING_NAME1 = 0,
 SETTING_NAME2 = 1,
...
}
```

and vector to hold and call the data

```
vector<bool> myVec;
if (myVec[SETTING_NAME1])
```

This should give me direct access, keep the size relatively small (since it's a bit based vector) as well as have the separation that I desired.

Comment: What exactly is not clean about your current code? Accessing booleans through a map (or vector, etc.) will definitely be slower than a simple memory access.

Comment: I guess it's just that, all those booleans just sitting inside my struct makes me feel like there should be a better way. So as far as your aware theres no direct access alternative that I could structure them better?

Comment: @user4815162342 It's not very scalable or maintainable

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername How does the proposed `map` scale any better, what is the difference? One still has to enumerate all settings, and they are still accessed by (some sort) of name. (The new code even has a bug in the `enum`, so maybe the new code is *less* maintainable.) The old code had no unnecessary repetition, and can be easily extended to support settings that are not boolean. This is not the case with the rewrite, which is limited to bools without a good reason.

Comment: @user4815162342 Bugs doesn't mean the code isn't maintainable (see more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintainability). Regarding scaling, when adding a new boolean with "if approach", besides declaring it there is a need to update and query it explicitly in every relevant place. Using map *relies* on the fact that the conditions are boolean, allowing to use a generalized data structure to handle them and automate some tasks, such as iterating over the conditions. It's also generally a healthier approach to separate data from code.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Adding a new boolean with the `enum` approach requires exactly the same effort - adding it to the `enum` (and to the map, if the default value is not false) and querying it where it is used. Regarding "iterating over the conditions", there is no indication that the OP needs this - a classic case of [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). As far as anyone can tell, there is exactly *nothing* wrong with the original code.

Comment: @user4815162342 Whether anything is wrong with the original code depends on the project requirements (and their expected changes). Regarding the effort of adding to enum - the point is that the initial effort isn't more or less but that the effort required to sustain upcoming changes should be minimized. Iterating over was just an example. Large software has a tendency to change. Experienced developer should expect *reasonable* changes

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Precisely - without knowing the actual requirements, it is impossible to tell whether the proposed change actually improves the code. If it is needed to iterate over all configuration options (or implement an editor for them), then it makes sense to add them to a mapping, although not of the kind presented by the OP. If the expected requirement is to support non-boolean options, then the change makes the code *harder* to change. The OP only mentioned efficiency of access, for which the switch to enum is incorrect as well. I still call YAGNI.

Comment: @user4815162342 It's not really harder to support non-boolean options. All is needed to do is to switch the vector to the desired types. It will still need to be of the same type, that's part of the abstraction. If a need arises to support different types, a design change should be applied instead of patching the code (it can still boil down to a vector of objects of newly defined type, thus minimizing the required changes from other modules that interface this one).

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername It's harder simply because the alternate code provided in the question doesn't support non-boolean options at all, so additional code would need to be written (possibly accompanied by an abstraction layer). Which is - again - more complication to replace code that was perfectly fine to begin with.

Comment: @user4815162342 You keep talking about perfectly fine code, while you don't know the requirements. I'm talking about general software qualities - scalability and maintainability. These things are pretty fundamental when writing complex and evolving software and if not taken care of will cause significant troubles in the future. Vector can easily hold integers instead of booleans and `if (vec[i])` can be converted to `if(vec[i] == someValue)` in a straightforward way.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername You don't know the requirements either. The vector-of-integers solution you propose fails with something as basic as supporting string settings. The original code, on the other hand, is just fine with that change (and with many others). At this point you are not adding anything new to the discussion, other than repeating vague appeals to "scalability and maintainability".

Comment: @user4815162342 Unlike yourself, I never claimed to know the requirements. Merely pointed out the importance of good software engineering practices. Regarding strings - besides the fact that it's somewhere on borderline for what can be considered a reasonable change in this case, it's implementable just as easily. Strings in C++ can be compared with operator ==, you know... (not that it has any crucial importance here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing a bool directly is obviously going to be faster than accessing it via a map or anything else. *However*, this is unlikely to *ever* be performance critical and the differences are going to be negligible.

I'd advise not worrying about performance *at all* for something like this if it interferes one iota with writing the clearest possible code. Worrying about this is a waste of time and premature optimization for no gain. The *best* thing you can do is write clear, understandable code and then trust the compilers optimizer and spend your time optimizing code in performance critical areas (determined by profiling of course, not just intuition/guessing) where it will make an actual difference.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's obviously going to be always faster, though. Besides depending on map implementation, there are also compiler and processor optimizations to consider and hw aspects, such as caching and platform architecture.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is a `bitmap`.

`long long int bitmask;` or depends on how many booleans you have.

then you can do stuff like

`bool checkMask(long long int bitmask, int check) { return bitmask & (1 << check) }`
 where check is like an index of a boolean, which can be set in an `enum class` or w\e.

It's definitly not better performance than using straight booleans, but it gives you some nice ways of managing a lot of booleans.

You should check about bitmasks online, I'm sure `std` has something built for this.

Comment: What would the OP gain from using a bitmap here? The indices still have to be stored and organized somewhere.

Comment: I mean, he has many states to keep. Each boolean stands for something. If he uses a bitmask and an enum, he'll still be keeping the naming of everything and he won't have to save so many unused bits (since you can use every bit in a bitmask, but not every bit in a boolean). So instead of having a variable for each boolean, he'll have one bitmask (or several, depending on amount of booleans), and check them like you check bitmasks, using an enum he has. It might not be as effective, but it's a lot more elegant than saving lots and lots of boolean variables.

Comment: I don't see how replacing named constants with named constants plus a bit-field helps anything. Unless you have many parallel configurations (bit-fields) at run-time that can all share the same index constants. But I'm not sure if this is the case here.

Comment: I look at it from my perspective. you define an enum, each with consecutive values, and when you do a `bitmask & (1 << enumval)`, you get a boolean in `enumval` index. I think that's a pretty nice thing to have. Lets continue. For each boolean value you have 7 bits that are left unused, whereas bitmask allows you to use every bit. I know that's not much, but it's something. Runtime operations are a lot easier as well. Since you can just test the bitmask with integer values from whatever you're doing, you can't do it with many variables. If you look at it `clean code` wise, bitmask wins.

Comment: That's not clean, why would the user want to use a cumbersome `checkMask(mask, data)` instead of a simple `if`? Not to mention that it's bound by the size of `long long`.

Comment: You're looking it at as if that's black and white. It's all situational. I think that for his problem, the bitmask option is an optimized version of his proposal. Bitmasks are very dynamic, and in my team's product, which is a database, we use bitmasks even though we have an extremely small amount of `"booleans"` (< 5), because they answer our need (hide-masks and show-masks). Believe me, there are some situations you would want bitmasks, and some where you wouldn't. Every programming problem has many solutions, the question is what's the most fitting one. That's my (1 << 1) cents.